# Know the creator for an azure resource

Tags: azure

Is there a way to find who among the subscription admins has created a azure resource, either using the portal or though powershell commands. I have tried using Get-AzureRmLog, however it returned resourceId property as empty for all the results and I couldn't figure out the right property to check for 'created' action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Activity Log from the new portal. It's under Management Services - Operation Logs in the old portal.

Comment: If the resource is older than 90 days you won't see it.

Answer (score 1):

The portal will work per previous answer, on the Activity Log blade the "Event Initiated By" column will have the user name that initiated the request. Get-AzureRMLog will also work and you'll want to pay attention to the caller property. The likely reason you are seeing this as a blank entry is that they are fabric initiated events, instead of events initiated by a unique user. If you want to search for a particular caller, use the -StartTime and -Caller parameters. Unless you archive your logs to a storage account, retention is 90 days, so ensure you're searching for an activity that has happened in the past 90 days.

Comment: Any way to see it if it is older than 90 days?

Comment: Not unless you send your audit logs to an external system.